Alternative to NAudio for reading soundfiles in C#?
I am using NAudio to read a file stream of an audiofile and using the resulting double[] vector to create a spectrogram:
private List<double[]> CreateFFTs(double[] audio, int sampleRate)
{
  SpectrogramGenerator sg = new SpectrogramGenerator(sampleRate, 4096, 500, MIN_FREQUENCY, MAX_FREQUENCY);
  sg.Add(audio);
  return sg.GetFFTs();
}

...
using (AudioFileReader afr = new AudioFileReader(audiofile))
{
  int sampleRate = afr.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
  int bytesPerSample = afr.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8;
  int sampleCount = (int)(afr.Length / bytesPerSample);
  int channelCount = afr.WaveFormat.Channels;
  var audio = new List<double>(sampleCount);
  var buffer = new float[sampleRate * channelCount];
  int samplesRead = 0;
  while ((samplesRead = afr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    audio.AddRange(buffer.Take(samplesRead).Select(x => x * 1d));
    currentBuffers++;
    if (currentBuffers > maxBuffers)
    {
      result.AddRange(CreateFFTs(audio.ToArray(), sampleRate));
      audio = new List<double>(sampleCount);
      currentBuffers = 0;
    }
  }
  result.AddRange(CreateFFTs(audio.ToArray(), sampleRate));
}

Now this works pretty well ... as long as you are on a Windows system. My tool is part of a tool chain that is supposed to run on a linux server, but NAudio is too heavily tied to the Windows API and thus not working on a linux server. Now I just need a library that replaces the AudioFileReader from NAudio and simply gives me the double[] vector with the data for any given soundfile (wave, mp3, ...)
Alternatives I found ususally focusing on playing the audiofile, but I just need the data ...
Thanks in advance,
Frank
I was looking for an simply to use alternative to NAudio, but didn't find the desired functionality.
